# Uniqueness of an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

let's say I have the following data structure:

```
   var someList=  new List<int>[]{
                     new List<int>() {-1,-1,2},
                     new List<int>() {-1,0,1}
                   });
```

I need to able to avoid:

```
someList.Add(new int[] {-1,1,0});
```

since [-1,0,1] are in the set already and I cannot allow duplicate sets.

Values can come in any other and still I need to ensure that there are no duplicates. So [0,-1,1] or [1,-1,0] are basically the same set.

This data structure will receive thousands of entries.

What do you think is the best way to ensure uniqueness?

I thought about using a dictionary, however, I am not quite sure since I will be increasing the memory and probably processing and I wonder if it is avoidable.

Comment: `HashSet` eliminates duplicates. As for not being quite sure about memory and processing time: benchmark and profile. If your sets and/or your elements are always small there are many ways to optimize this in terms of storage and/or processing time, but premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: instead of declaring var someArray as a list use a Set<T> of a custom wrapper to List<int> and define in there an equals method so you can tell apart duplicated elements

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert I will certainly try it

Comment: Also, @Dalorzo your `someArray` is an array of Lists, so it has no `Add` method.

Comment: I can change List for another data structure such as hashset

Comment: The new list must be exactly the same, in any order? What about `[-1,1]`  or `[-1,1,0,1]`?

Comment: Values can come in any order

Comment: By the way, Arrays don't have an `Add` method.  You can replace things at an index, but an array of length 2 will always have items in the array.

Comment: Create a wrapper class that includes a `List` and delegates most of the collection work to the list.  Have your class implement value semantics (Equals, GetHashCode, etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type). Make it so that the class implements your definition of Equals (_Values can come in any order_).  Make the outer collection a HashSet

Comment: How long are the entries likely to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet` guarantees uniqueness, but list, array or hashset are compared by reference, not their elements values, so you should implement your own comparer, like below. We order them first to guarantee that the order doesn't matter.

```
class SequenceComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<int> a,IEnumerable<int> b){
        if(a==null && b==null)
            return true;
        
        if(a==null || b==null)
            return false;       

        return a.OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual(b.OrderBy(x=>x));      
    }
    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<int> a){
        var hashCode = new HashCode();      
        foreach(var el in a.OrderBy(x=>x)){
            hashCode.Add(el);
        }       
        return hashCode.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

So, you can do like the following:

```
var comparer = new SequenceComparer();
var someArray = new HashSet<List<int>>(comparer){
                 new List<int>() {-1,-1,2},
                 new List<int>() {-1,0,1}
               };
someArray.Add(new List<int>() {-1,1,0});
```

Comment: Your use of `HashCode.Combine` isn't how it should be done - you should have `var result = new HashCode();` ... `result.Add(el);`...`return result.ToHashCode();`

Comment: @NetMage Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: if speed is critical you could even create a wrapper for List, and pre-calculate the hashcode. That would avoid using some iteratorst and doing some operations. I've not benchmarked, though...

Comment: It may also pay to make the comparer for `List<int>` and compare the lengths of `a` and `b` before calling `SequenceEqual`, which I don't believe will be able to optimize after `OrderBy`, assuming they are not all length 3.